# How to refactor linq predicate into Func variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
if (model.Id > 0)
{
  return _buyerRepository.Exists(x => (model.Id != x.Id) &&
      (x.IdentificationNumber == model.IdentificationNumber));
}

return _buyerRepository.Exists(x =>
    x.IdentificationNumber == model.IdentificationNumber);
```

How to extract `(model.Id != x.Id)` and to put in the linq query based on if `model.Id>0` or it's a `0` ?
I am thinking on ExpressionTrees and Func<T,bool>, but Im not sure how to put a condition.

Comment: Are you asking, how can I do this all in one query?

Comment: You know you could have just written `(model.Id == 0 || model.Id != x.Id)` ?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have a Func expression which will do a check if Id >0 or 0, and based on that to return `true` or to return a predicate like `(model.Id != x.Id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move from `Exists` to `Any` and do the following:

```
IEnumerable<T> query = (IEnumerable<T>)_buyerRepository;
if (model.Id > 0)
  query = query.Where(x => model.Id != x.Id);

return query.Any(x => x.IdentificationNumber == model.IdentificationNumber);
```

See an example here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EkoDym

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { Id = 1, IdentificationNumber = "1" },
            new Foo() { Id = 2, IdentificationNumber = "2" },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(HasAny(foos, 1, "1"));
        Console.WriteLine(HasAny(foos, 0, "1"));
        
        
        var foosv2 = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { Id = 2, IdentificationNumber = "1" },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(HasAny(foosv2, 1, "1"));
        Console.WriteLine(HasAny(foosv2, 2, "1"));
    }
    
    static bool HasAny(List<Foo> foos, int id, string identificationNumber)
    {
        IEnumerable<Foo> query = (IEnumerable<Foo>)foos;
        if (id > 0)
            query = query.Where(x => id != x.Id);

        return query.Any(x => x.IdentificationNumber == identificationNumber);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In case you may believe that the `Where` condition will be evaluated for all items before `Any` you don't have to worry about it that is the laziness of LINQ and `Where` will only be evaluated till `Any` finds a result.

You can see here a demo:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wen09a

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { Id = 1, IdentificationNumber = "1" },
            new Foo() { Id = 2, IdentificationNumber = "2" },
            
            new Foo() { Id = 3, IdentificationNumber = "3" },
            new Foo() { Id = 4, IdentificationNumber = "4" },
            new Foo() { Id = 5, IdentificationNumber = "5" },
            new Foo() { Id = 6, IdentificationNumber = "6" },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(HasAny(foos, 1, "2"));
    }
    
    static bool HasAny(List<Foo> foos, int id, string identificationNumber)
    {
        IEnumerable<Foo> query = (IEnumerable<Foo>)foos;
        if (id > 0)
            query = query.Where(x => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Compare Ids - {id} and {x.Id}");
                return id != x.Id;
            });

        return query.Any(x => x.IdentificationNumber == identificationNumber);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Even though I have declared the Ids 3 to 6 which would all be unequal to the id 1 it will stop searching on the first positive value for Any.